# What is half of a medal?

Tags: olympics, awards

I see on http://www.nbcolympics.com/medals :

[image]

Why is there 0.5 of a medal?

Answer (score 2):

A recent blog post by [Daniel Marcelino](http://danielmarcelino.github.io/blog/2016/yet-the-worst-olympic-chart.html) seems to indicate what I had suspected.  A half of a medal (for statistical purposes) is awarded if an event has a “tie” for the Gold, Silver, or Bronze.

From Daniel’s Blog…

> Yep, that’s right; one can get half a medal by tying for a placement.

Comment: This makes sense to me, except that the IOC doesn't seem to treat things this way (their medal lists are always whole numbers).  But this may be how NBC is treating it.

Comment: I doubt that's right. Canada's Penny Oleksiak won a gold medal in 100m swimming tied with an American and Canada's got one gold medal, not 0.5.

Comment: @Goldorak84 for statistical purposes, I believe it is correct.